# How to find the shortest path to complete all the task

Tags: python, graph

I have a project that work on a AVG routing, which means that Robot walking around to transfer goods.

I am required to find the quickest path to complete the all the transfer tasks. It means that I need to find the shortest path that the robot walk.Ｉ have looked at **Dijkstra's algorithm** and **travel salesman problem** But all of this are based on nodes and I am thinking how to apply that into my case

Explanation for my case :

Robot will be get a duty list that contain two nodes ( start_nodes , end_nodes)

**SAMPLE CASE**

```
Start: x: 650 y:200 End: x:900 y:400
Start: x: 700 y:150 End: x:200 y:100
Start: x: 750 y:250 End: x:900 y:100
Start: x: 100 y:250 End: x:100 y:100
Start: x: 500 y:300 End: x:800 y:200
```

I need to find the order for completing this tasks so that the robot can walk the shortest route. IF the robotic is located in (300,300). How should i figure out the case.

Also if i have two robot or more later, how should I implement?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you are asking what algorithm to use to find the shortest path, you might have more luck on the [math.se] stack site. If you are asking specifically how to implement it in code, then please provide a [mcve] for your issue including code for what you've already tried

Comment: For simplicity, It means that finding the shortest path between the tasks. I dont know where to start to code.I have generate all the duty list but dont know how to find the best path to finish all the task. Best means fastest.